# Interprocess Communications between Dyalog APL and q

Tags: kdb, apl, dyalog

How would I connect a Dyalog APL Client to reach out to a q server and execute a simple transaction (like "2+2")?  The protocol seems simple enough and very well documented when it comes to decoding the answer, but I can't seem to get past the very first step, the initial handshaking, either with Dyalog APL or VBA.  For now, if I could get to localhost, that would be enough.

The documentation I was using is https://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/ipcprotocol

Answer (score 2):

For Dyalog APL, you'd use Conga (Dyalog's TCP/IP utility library).
The [Conga User Guide](http://docs.dyalog.com/16.0/Conga%20User%20Guide.pdf) contains good examples on how to create simple text-based TCP/IP clients.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I would prefer to stick with native Dyalog TCP/IP.

Comment: I'm curious about your desire to stay with the obsolete TCP objects. Conga connections are easier to set up, take down and handle errors on - they have a host of new features to make application development easier :-). Can you tell us anything about the reasons for this preference?

Answer (score 2):

I got a prototype of a Q interface up and running a few years ago, handling most of the basic data types. It is based on Conga - rewriting it for the old TCPSocket objects should not be too hard, but not something that we are planning to do since they are now considered obsolete.

I should put the code up on GitHub but am a little pressed for time this week; if you can't wait a week or so, send me an e-mail (mkrom@...com), let me know which version of Dyalog APL you are running and I'll send you my workspace containing the code.

Comment: Thanks for your offer to help.  I'm in no hurry and look forward to finding the code on GitHub sometime soon.

Comment: Please take a look at https://github.com/mkromberg/qconnect and let me know if you are able to get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

Kimmo Linna, a user of both kdb+ and Dyalog APL, has posted done some work to update and enhance my work on qconnect - you can find it at https://github.com/kimmolinna/qconnect